# Refused to display 'https://script.google.com/' in a frame because it set 'X-Frame-Options' to 'sameorigin'

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

```
function doPost(e){  
  AddRecord(e.parameter.aoutlet, e.parameter.vendor, e.parameter.itemslist, e.parameter.billamt, 'img');
  var htmlOutput =  HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile('Ex_form');
  htmlOutput.message = 'Record Added';
  return htmlOutput.evaluate();
}
```

I know Google does not like to embed itself into other site but this error occurs in Google Apps Script when I'm testing my deployment...why? I havent even used iframe in my html file(Ex_form)

Comment: Can I ask you about the method for requesting the function of `doPost`?

Comment: I've put doPost entirely out of scene now. I was doing <form action="<? url ?>" method="post"> where url was ScriptApp.getService().getUrl(). Now I'm just doing google.script.runAddRecord() plus I'm getting AJAX like behaviour which is great... So I'll solve this error next time if I needed to

Comment: Thank you for replying. I'm glad your issue was resolved. If your issue was resolved, can you post it as an answer? By this, it will be useful for other users who have the same issue.